# empty legend Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

I am trying to superimpose markers on a bar plot to highlight significant differences...
with the following code everything is fine

```
            figure
            y = [1 2 3 4];
            bar(y);
            ylim([0 6])
            p05=1;
            p01=2;
            p001=3;

            l1 = line(p05, 5, ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', '*', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );     


           l2 = line(p01, 5, ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', 'x', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );


           l3 =    line(p001, 5, ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', 'o', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );                

            leg = legend([l1,l2,l3],{'p<0.05','p<0.01','p<0.001'});
            legend('boxoff')
            set(leg,'FontSize',8);
```

Some times I have (for example) `p05 = []` and the legend becomes wrong... what I mean is that the the second marker is associated to p<0.05...

```
            figure
            y = [1 2 3 4];
            bar(y);
            ylim([0 6])
            p05=[];
            p01=2;
            p001=3;

            l1 = line(p05, [], ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', '*', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );     


           l2 = line(p01, 5, ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', 'x', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );


           l3 =    line(p001, 5, ...
                    'linestyle', 'none', ...
                    'marker', 'o', ...
                    'markersize', 5 ...
                    );                

            leg = legend([l1,l2,l3],{'p<0.05','p<0.01','p<0.001'});
            legend('boxoff')
            set(leg,'FontSize',8);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found the solution...

```
            lines_n = [l1,l2,l3];
            cc = [isempty(p05) isempty(p01) isempty(p001)];
            legend_names = {'p<0.05','p<0.01','p<0.001'};
            legend_names(cc)=[];


            leg = legend(lines_n,legend_names);
            legend('boxoff')
            set(leg,'FontSize',8);
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answers that helped you, even if its yours